# Android SDK 30 WebView is giving error. How to ignore/fix the error?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I am trying to use a javascript(index.browser.js) file inside a android webview. When i try to run the app it's crashing with the below error, stating there are some issue with the script file.

`[INFO:CONSOLE(139)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('"`

But the same index.browser.js file is working perfectly in android SDK 29 and below. And i have tested the file in browser also by creating a html file and pointing the script file, There are no issues at all.

Example:

```
<script src="index.browser.js"></script>
```

But it's not working in SDK 30, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try 
webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working

Comment: The error can be in the line/code before the line you posted.

Comment: `API 30, ` ??? You mean SDK 30? Please correct your post and subject.

Comment: in SDK 29 also i am getting the same error message, but it didn't crash the application, the app works fine.

It's only in SDK 30 where the app crashes after this error.